# Sencha Touch 2 Carousel: Lock Swiping of Start/End Page

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, carousel, swipe

I want Carousel to stop swiping at start and end of the pages.
I mean to prevent the **end** page to **swipe** to the **right** and the **start** page to **swipe** to the **left**:

[image: Carousel]

Is there any config or some other way to implement it?

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Check this out LockableCarousel class: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9365898/862474

Answer (score 1):

By default, ST2's [`carousel`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.carousel.Carousel) component has this configuration. So, *you need not* put in any extra effort to achieve this.

Look at [`this`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.carousel.Carousel) example from Sencha's website. When you reach the last item, it will prevent swiping to the right and when you are on first item, it will prevent swiping to the left.

```
Ext.create('Ext.Carousel', {
    fullscreen: true,

    defaults: {
        styleHtmlContent: true
    },

    items: [
        {
            html : 'Item 1',
            style: 'background-color: #5E99CC'
        },
        {
            html : 'Item 2',
            style: 'background-color: #759E60'
        },
        {
            html : 'Item 3'
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Maybe I didn't exactly explain what I wanted. For the last card, it is swipe to the right BUT automatically swipe back and prevents swiping. Ok. But I don't want this. I don't want to even swipe to right then go back. I want to 'Lock' swiping the last card. In the above example, I don't want to see the White background when I swipe to left on 'Item 1' card. Could I explain what I wanted? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own carousel and then override the onDrag event following is the code form Ext.carousel.Carousel

```
Ext.define('Ext.carousel.Custom', {
    extend: 'Ext.carousel.Carousel',

    onDrag: function(e) {
        if (!this.isDragging) {
            return;
        }

        var startOffset = this.dragStartOffset,
            direction = this.getDirection(),
            delta = direction === 'horizontal' ? e.deltaX : e.deltaY,
            lastOffset = this.offset,
            flickStartTime = this.flickStartTime,
            dragDirection = this.dragDirection,
            now = Ext.Date.now(),
            currentActiveIndex = this.getActiveIndex(),
            maxIndex = this.getMaxItemIndex(),
            lastDragDirection = dragDirection,
            offset;

        if ((currentActiveIndex === 0 && delta > 0) || (currentActiveIndex === maxIndex && delta < 0)) {
            delta *= 0.5;
        }

        offset = startOffset + delta;

        if (offset > lastOffset) {
            dragDirection = 1;
        }
        else if (offset < lastOffset) {
            dragDirection = -1;
        }

        if (dragDirection !== lastDragDirection || (now - flickStartTime) > 300) {
            this.flickStartOffset = lastOffset;
            this.flickStartTime = now;
        }

        this.dragDirection = dragDirection;

        // now that we have the dragDirection, we should use that to check if there
        // is an item to drag to
        if ((dragDirection == 1 && currentActiveIndex == 0) || (dragDirection == -1 && currentActiveIndex == maxIndex)) {
            return;
        }

        this.setOffset(offset);
    }
});
```

reference :=[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410934/disable-carousel-overscroll-overdrag-in-sencha-touch)